# How to set orientation = landscape using KnpSnappyBundle?

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using Snappy Bundle along with Symfony 2.1.

I have some question I did not find in the documentation of this bundle :

- How to set the orientation ?
- Is there a way to display page numbers ?

Here is my config.yml for the bundle :

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /home/wkhtmltopdf-i386
        options:    []
```

Here is one of my Controller to generate a pdf :

```
public function exampleAction() {
    $html = $this->renderView('MyBundle:Example:test.pdf.twig', $this->param);  
    return new Response($this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),200, array(
    'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="Test.pdf"'));

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$pdf = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html,
                                   array('orientation'=>'Landscape',
                                         'default-header'=>true));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that does not work as I have the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\LoggableGenerator::setOption()"

Comment: I tried your code and also $pdf = ($this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html), 200,
                                   array('orientation'=>'Landscape',
                                         'default-header'=>true,'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="Test.pdf"')); But that does not work :(

Comment: You've put the parameters in the wrong location, it should look like this: `return new Response($this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html, array('orientation'=>'Landscape', 'default-header'=>true)), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf', 'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="Test.pdf"')));`

Comment: You know what would really be nice?  A link to some documentation.  I don't see any reference to an 'orientation' option in the Snappy README ~ https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: KNP Snappy is actually a wrapper for a WKHTMLTOPDF shell utility. Here is a link to its manual: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt and you will find "orientation" and all other options in it.

Comment: if you have one document with 2 pages: first page is Landscape and the other one is portrait! How I can do it?